# React child components don't re-render when mapped from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-component

I'm loading some react components on demand (among with other information) depending on user input.
The components to render are kept in an array and the render method uses `array.map` to include the components.

The problem is, that if I trigger a `forceUpdate()` of the main app component, the mapped components won't update.

Code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-components-map-from-array-ekfb7

Comment: `forceUpdate` is not something you should use except for very special cases. It's almost certainly an indication that something else is set up incorrectly.

Comment: Also storing component instances in state is an anti-pattern. Instead store identifiers in state, and create the instances in your `map` callback.

Comment: It's part of a bigger project using `i18n-react` for localizations. If the user changes the language, I trigger a `forceUpdate` off the app root component to update all translations.

Comment: Storing the identifiers only would make the callback whole more complex, since the components to map will be different components and may take additional parameters. But I will keep this in mind.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a single identifier, that's just usually all you need. If you need a complex set of information about each new component, just store an object. I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates are not updating because you are creating the instance of the component in your `add` function, and from then on you are referencing that instance without letting react manage the updates.

This is why storing component instances in state or in other variables is an anti-pattern.

#### Demonstration of the problem

Below I've created a working example still using `forceUpdate` just to prove what the issue is.

Notice instead of putting the component in state, I'm just pushing to the array to increase it's length. Then React can manage the updates correctly.

```js
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>{Date.now()}</p>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.comps = [1];
  }

  add() {
    this.comps.push(1);
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Components map example</h1>
        <p></p>
        <h2>Static TestComponent (ok):</h2>
        <TestComponent />
        <h2>TestComponents mapped from an array (not ok):</h2>
        {this.comps.map((comp, id) => {
          return <div key={id}><TestComponent /></div>;
        })}
        <h2>All should update when the App component renders</h2>
        <p>
          <button onClick={() => this.add()}>Add TestComponent</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.forceUpdate()}>forceUpdate App</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This is still a less than ideal solution. But it does show where the issue lies.

#### A better solution

If you need to know more about each component instance up front, you can make the array more complex.

I would also suggest using state to store the `comps` array, and removing `forceUpdate` completely.

```js
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>{Date.now()} {this.props.a} {this.props.b}</p>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      comps: [{ a: 'a', b: 'b' }]
    }
  }

  add = () => {
    // add your custom props here
    this.setState(prev => ({comps: [ ...prev.comps, { a: 'c', b: 'd' } ]}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Components map example</h1>
        <p></p>
        <h2>Static TestComponent (ok):</h2>
        <TestComponent />
        <h2>TestComponents mapped from an array (not ok):</h2>
        {this.state.comps.map((compProps, id) => {
          return <div key={id}><TestComponent {...compProps} /></div>;
        })}
        <h2>All should update when the App component renders</h2>
        <p>
          <button onClick={() => this.add()}>Add TestComponent</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Now notice that each component in the `map` callback can have it's own unique set of props based on whatever logic you what. But the parts that should re-render will do so correctly.

Comment: I think your "better solution" is nearly what I need. If I store the component class reference too, then I'm able to map multiple different component types with different properties. Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-components-map-from-array-forked-itgnp) of what I mean. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In order to update in React, you have to put your data in the state and then `setState`.

`setState()` schedules an update to a component’s state object. When state changes, the component responds by re-rendering which means updating the screen with the new state.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>{Date.now()}</p>;
  }
}

export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      comps: [<TestComponent />],
    }
  }

  add = () => {
    this.setState({ comps: this.state.comps.concat(<TestComponent />) })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Components map example</h1>
        <p></p>
        <h2>Static TestComponent (ok):</h2>
        <TestComponent />

        <h2>TestComponents mapped from an array (not ok):</h2>
        {
          this.state.comps.map((comp, id) => {
            return <div key={id}>{comp}</div>;
          })
        }

        <h2>All should update when the App component renders</h2>
        <p>
          <button onClick={this.add}>Add TestComponent</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if I'm using the state as you described, the mapped TestComponents doesn't update. See https://codesandbox.io/s/react-components-map-from-array-forked-ru5zj and click the "forceUpdate App" button.

Comment: why do you need to use `forceUpdate`? Why not just use `setState`?

Comment: he wants to know why the mapped TestComponents doesn't update

Comment: It's part of a bigger project using `i18n-react` for localizations. If the user changes the language, I trigger a `forceUpdate` off the app root component to update all translations. It's working fine, expect that the mapped components are not updated.